# Что вы используете для нагрузочного тестирования?

Tags: юнит-тесты, тестирование, testng, нагрузочное-тестирование

Используете ли вы нагрузочное тестирование, и если да, то что вы используете? JMeter, Яндекс.Танк? Хочу узнать какие решения вообще есть и какие популярны. И какие практики применяются. Может быть кто-то их к дженкинсу подключает для автоматического запуска раз в неделю, может кто-то использует какие-то свои внутренние решения в компании. Буду рад любой информации

Comment: Нагрузочное тестирование чего?

Comment: @VTT web api, http/https

Comment: в нашей компании используется jmeter. CI/DI запускает эти тесты на каждый rc билд. Сам jmeter запускается из докера.

Answer (score 1):

Из доступных (читай "бесплатных") и живых вариантов у нас имеется (известных мне):

- JMeter - пробовал, надоело кнопки тыкать, по мне так не самое гибкое решение (гибкое - см.ниже) + community версия может глючить.
- Яндекс.Танк - не пробовал.
- Locust (https://locust.io/) - использовал именно его. Скрипты нагрузки на python, после запуска поднимается веб-морда на ней статистика RPS и прочему.

Систематически нагрузку не проводил. Только по запросу. В пайплайны CI тоже встраивал (да и это очень редкая практика, даже не знаю есть ли необходимость в этом - по мне так, гораздо интереснее для части продуктов снимать быстродействие фронта)